# Alternative method of keeping Html placeholder

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, razor-2

I have a **Registration Form** in Razor syntax as shown below

```
    <div id="RegisterDiv" class="is-hidden">
    @using (Html.BeginForm("Register", "User", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "frmRegister" }))
    {            

        <label>Email</label>
        @Html.TextBoxFor(lm => lm.Email, new { id = "Email", name = "Email", value = "", placeholder = "Enter your email" })
        <small id="Emailerror" class="error is-hidden">A valid email address is required</small>

        <label>Password</label>
        @Html.PasswordFor(lm => lm.Password, new { id = "Password", name = "Password", value = "", maxlength = "20" })
        <small id="Passworderror" class="error is-hidden"></small>      
        @Html.PasswordFor(lm => lm.VerifyPassword, new { id = "VerifyPassword", name = "VerifyPassword", value = "", maxlength = "20" })
        <small id="VerifyPassworderror" class="error is-hidden"></small>
        <small class="help-block">* must be 6-20 characters (letters, numbers and hyphens are accepted but not spaces)</small>

        <hr>
        <div class="form-row">
            <div class="six columns">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(lm => lm.FirstName, new { id = "FirstName", name = "FirstName", value = "", placeholder = "First Name" })
                <small id="FirstNameerror" class="error is-hidden">First name is required</small>
            </div>
            <div class="six columns">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(lm => lm.LastName, new { id = "LastName", name = "LastName", value = "", placeholder = "Last Name" })
                <small id="LastNameerror" class="error is-hidden">Last name is required</small>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-row">
            <div class="six columns">
                @Html.DropDownListFor(dr => dr.CountryId, new SelectList(Model.CountryList, "countryid", "name"), "Country of Residence", new { id = "CountryId", name = "CountryId" })
                <small id="CountryIderror" class="error is-hidden">Country is required</small>
            </div>
        </div>            
        <div class="form-action">
            <a id="Submit" class="form-submit" href="javaScript:void(0);">Register</a>
            <a id="Cancel" class="form-cancel" href="javaScript:void(0);">Cancel</a>
        </div>
    }
</div>
```

And the submit code is

```
$("#frmRegister").submit();
```

But when the application is run on IE-8 the values of elements id="*Password*" and id="*VerifyPassword*" are not being sent to server. On removing the *placeholder* attribute it works fine,that is data is beng sent to server. Is there any fix for this issue with out removing placeholder attribute ? If not is there any alternative way of keeping a placeholder other than like `placeholder = "Verify Password"` ?

Answer (score 0):

The `placeholder` attribute is a new attribute in html5, meaning that pre-html5 browsers will not work with them. 
You could give [Modernizr](http://modernizr.com/) a try, it's meant to make HTML5-only elements/attributes work on older browsers.
Of course you could make your own javascript function for placeholders, it's not very difficult. [jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/GyNZr/)